# Battery charged over USB and powering DC motors

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, usb, dc-motor

I need help with figuring out how to power DC motors in my project.

I need to power two 12V DC motors (they are connected in series) that will be controlled with momentary switch. The idea is to have them connected to get power from USB, but as I can get maximum of 5V from usb, I was thinking to add an battery which will get power from USB and battery will power the DC motors.

So, roughly that is the whole idea: have the battery charged from USB and that same battery to power the motors.

How can I do this? What kind of battery I need? I was looking through batteries with USB input and normal positive and negative output, but I can't seem to find anything like that. I am probably looking it wrong.

Comment: You can't power a 12V motor from a 5V battery (let alone 2 in series) unless you use some sort of DC-DC converter. It is unclear what you are trying to do, please elaborate.

Comment: I know I can't charge it from battery like that. As I stated, because I can't charge DC motors from USB (as doesn't give me enough power) I decided to get a battery to charge the motors - I am just not sure how to do it. Because I want the battery to be charged from USB at same time.

Comment: USB won't charge that battery.

Comment: can you explain me why? and what are my alternatives?

Comment: Two 12 V motors in series require a 24 V battery.

Comment: alright, and what if used 6V motors. meaning 12 V total... is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: Charging voltage must be >= battery voltage for charge current to flow. To use 5V to charge (from eg USB) you need a voltage converter - 5V in and suitable voltage out.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly drive a 12-volt motor, or charge a 12-volt battery, from a USB port. What you can do is to charge a 3.7 volt LiPo battery, then use that to drive a 3.3 volt to 12 volt DC-DC converter, and use the 12 volts to drive your motors. Actually, finding a 3.3 to 12 volt converter is difficult, and you might need to start with a 3.3 to 5 volt converter, then feed that to a 5 volt to 12 volt converter. Make sure to put a decent-sized capacitor on the output of the first converter.

The other thing you need to think about is just how much power you need to size your converters for. DC brushed motors are notorious for their startup current surge, so you will need a larger set of converters than you realize.

And it's almost certainly a good idea to make sure that your motor circuit disconnects the charger from the battery before you try to drive the motor.